3 buttons and 3 LEDs circuit with mutual exclusion
I want to create a simple game for 3 players with 3 push buttons and 3 LEDs. Each button turns on a specific LED. The challenging part is that I need mutual exclusion. Only the LED corresponding to the first button pressed should light up, and the others should remain off.
The game concept is this: A question is shown to 3 students. The first student who knows the answer presses their button and turns on their corresponding LED. Basically, I need to know who pressed first.
My knowledge on electronic is very basic (welding a few components) however I can learn anything, and I'm looking to the simplest way to accomplish this.

What bits of electronics to you want to explore with this project?  Basic/discrete parts, Logic gates & implementation, electro-mechanical relays, or even micro-controllers?  There are endless ways to accomplish this from a few SCR's to fun with programming.  What are your goals, restrictions, resources, and perhaps even budget concerns? - as all of that matters in the type of answers you will get.

Here's one of many ways. It's modular, so you add as many students as needed. Personally, I would probably do this with a microcontroller dev board or Arduino. But here's a hardware only version if you want to build something without software:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

This is the classic "game show" or "Jeopardy" circuit.  The first button pressed is registered and locks out any subsequent presses of all other buttons, until a master reset arrives.  Over the years, many circuits have been devised for this application, here are just two examples:
This one uses discrete components, specifically SCRs.  An SCR can be created using small-signal BJT:
https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/gameshow-buzzers-how-can-i-illuminate-only-the-first-pressed-button.184475/#post-1701696
This one uses logic gates:
https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/game-circuit.82641/
A search for "game show first button push" will yield a plethora of results from which to choose from.
Without knowing any other details about your particular application I cannot help further.  Details needed to select/design a suitable circuit are:

What power supply will be used.  Battery or mains operated?
Mechanical form-factor required, including the inputs (buttons) and outputs (LEDs).  This will determine things like buttons, LEDs, housing, interconnecting cables, radio-links, etc.
Interfacing - does this need to provide outputs to some external system?
Cost constraints, and production qty.  Is this a one-off, or are you planning to make thousands?  Selling into various markets requires compliance testing and certification, which can add significant costs to product development.


I designed and built one of these for a school, twenty years ago. Just used an Atmel (before Microchip bought them) AT90S2313, memory serving. Very simple assembly code. One cool thing is that there were exactly (luckily) 8 switches to monitor. So they were all on a single port and I debounced all the switches simultaneously, in parallel. We decided to use a button like this one. Today, there are also products like this.

As above, this is called a "game show" or "College Bowl" circuit.  If you search for 'game show circuit' or game show circuit schematic', you will get many examples of how to do this.
